# Menu not working on homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

As my title says, the menu is not working on homepage. However, the menu opens on all other pages. For instance this is a product page: https://guruseeds.in/product/cabbage-hybrid-f1/ Here if you click on the menu and hover over any menu item, the sub menu opens. But in the homepage (https://guruseeds.in/) if you hover over any menu item, the sub menu doesn’t open.

This is happening on both mobile and pc.  I tried everything for 2 days now, couldn't identify the cause. Need to fix this badly. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Note: Please reize your browser screen to a mobile size to view the mobile version of the website.

Comment: Please add your code and show/tell us what you have tried to fix this yourself.

Comment: It is not working in this page also https://guruseeds.in/product/cabbage-hybrid-f1/

Comment: @Rag Both the menus are different

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not your web site which will change or disappear making your question and the answers unusable to anyone. [mcve]

Comment: the problem likely is in your php code checking for is_home_page(). Please add your code so it can be troubleshooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this to your css :

```
.departments-menu .menu-item-has-children:hover .dropdown-menu, .vertical-menu .menu-item-has-children:hover .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    left: 100%;
    width: 212px;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

and this is for the mobile version .you have to add toggled class to your .handheld-navigation-wrapper element to see the menu:

```
<script>    
    $('.navbar-toggler').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.handheld-navigation-wrapper').toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It works on pc now. However, the code for mobile device is not working. I added the code to the header of the page.

Comment: I don't understand why this is happening, because the homepage menu looks exactly the same as the product page. I saw the pages using inspect tool and the class "handheld-navigation-wrapper" changes to "handheld-navigation-wrapper toggled" on click in the product page. I changed the class name to "handheld-navigation-wrapper toggled" in the homepage using inspect tool and the menu opened successfully and if I remove "toggled" the menu closes. I just don't understand why its not happening automatically on click. Please help.

Comment: Hello Rahele, I'm kind of stuck here. Any help would be highly appreciated. I added the script but the menu is not working on mobiles.

Comment: try deactive the plugins that you used in home page like the special offer box or the slider. maybe there is a conflict

Comment: and the menu in product page has a different code , when i changed the home page menu to product menu in developer tool it worked fine .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Everything was working perfectly until I implemented caching and CDN. Once I implemented caching and CDN the menu problem started and with your code I was able to make it work on larger screens. I have tried deactivating the caching and cdn and the problem just doesn't seem to go away. I'm afraid I had hit a dead end.

Comment: active your caching plugin and see if there is any option you can clear cache with that, then deactive the plugin .

Comment: I did purge all the cache before deactivating.